# Access Alternate Data Stream data from Thumbnail Image Handler code?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, windows-7

I'm trying to write a Thumbnail Image Handler for a custom file type based on Microsoft's example code here: [Building Thumbnail Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

As a proof of concept, I'm storing the base64 of a jpeg file into an ADS on my custom file.

My problem is that I'm not sure how to access this data from the DLL code. Microsoft's example uses base64 stored in an XML tag within the custom file type. I don't have the option to modify the internal components of my file type, leading me to using ADS as an example.

Is there a way to access an ADS from DLL handler code?

Comment: Your problem is not accessing ADS (that's easy), it's that you need a way to load a JPEG from a disk file. There are lots of solutions to this (e.g. gdiplus is an easy one). Once you've picked that, accessing an ADS is as easy as appending the name of the stream to the regular name of the file (e.g. c:\blah\file.moo:thumbnail)

Comment: And in order to get that filename, make sure your handler is implementing either `IInitializeWithFile`, with gives you the actual filename, or `IInitialializeWithItem`, which gives you an `IShellItem` that you can extract the filename from. `IInitializeWithStream` only gives you an `IStream`, which you cannot get a filename from.